# Android swipe refresh array IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter that holds channels. I use swipe refresh for refreshing list members. But when i pull down (refresh list) and immediately pull up to down on list i give IndexOutOfBoundsException. This is my adapter:

```
public class KanalAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    String kanaladi;
    String veritabani_id;
    ArrayList<Kanal> channelbaba;
    ArrayList<Kanal> kokchannelbaba;
    int OFFICIAL_KANAL = 0;
    int NORMAL_KANAL = 1;
    LayoutInflater lala;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    Filter kanalfilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = kokchannelbaba;
                results.count = kokchannelbaba.size();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Kanal> sonuclistesi = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Kanal i : kokchannelbaba) {
                    if (i.getKanaladi().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        sonuclistesi.add(i);
                    }
                }
                results.values = sonuclistesi;
                results.count = sonuclistesi.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                channelbaba = (ArrayList<Kanal>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public KanalAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Kanal> channelbaba) {
        this.context = context;
        this.channelbaba = channelbaba;
        kokchannelbaba = channelbaba;
        veritabani_id = SharedIdCek();
        kanaldakikisisayilari();
        lala = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.badooooo)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.badooooo)
                .showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.badooooo)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {
                        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 970, 260, false);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private String SharedIdCek() {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("kullaniciverileri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String veritabani_id = sp.getString("serverid", "defaultserverid");
        return veritabani_id;
    }

    private void kanaldakikisisayilari() {
        for (int i = 0; i < channelbaba.size(); i++) {
            ServerKanaldakiKisiSayisi sKKS = new ServerKanaldakiKisiSayisi(i);
            sKKS.execute(channelbaba.get(i).getKanaladi());
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (channelbaba.size());
    }

    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return channelbaba.get(i);
    }

    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object item = getItem(position-1);
        Kanal kanal = (Kanal) item;
        if (kanal.official) {
            return OFFICIAL_KANAL;
        } else {
            return NORMAL_KANAL;
        }
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        KanalHolder holder = null;
        final int pozisyon = position;
        Object currentKanal = getItem(position);
        Kanal kanal = (Kanal) currentKanal;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new KanalHolder();
            if (kanal.official) {
                convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.officialkanal, null);
                holder.officialgenel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                holder.officialkanaladitext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                holder.menubutonu = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
                holder.officialkisisayisi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
                holder.officiallikesayisi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView27);
            }
            if (!kanal.official) {
                convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.normalkanal, null);
                holder.normalgenel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                holder.normalkanaladi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                holder.normalkisisayisi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                holder.normallikesayisi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (KanalHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (kanal.official) {
            holder.officialgenel.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.cropped);
            holder.officialkanaladitext.setText(channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi());
            holder.officiallikesayisi.setText(String.valueOf(channelbaba.get(position).getLikesayisi()));
            holder.officialgenel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    kanaladi = channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi();
                    String kanalid = channelbaba.get(position).getId();
                    int likedurumu = channelbaba.get(position).getLikedurumu();
                    Log.i("tago", "adapter like durumu" + likedurumu);
                    KanalaElemanEkle kEE = new KanalaElemanEkle();
                    kEE.execute(kanaladi);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GrupSohbeti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("intentname", "kanaladapter");
                    intent.putExtra("kanalmodu", "o");
                    intent.putExtra("kanaladi", kanaladi);
                    intent.putExtra("kanallikedurumu", likedurumu);
                    intent.putExtra("kanalid", kanalid);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        if (!kanal.official) {
            Kanal objectt = channelbaba.get(position);
            if(holder.normalgenel.getTag()==null ||!holder.normalgenel.getTag().equals(objectt.getKanalurl())){
                ImageAware imageAvare = new ImageViewAware(holder.normalgenel,false);
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(channelbaba.get(position).getKanalurl(), imageAvare, options);
                holder.normalgenel.setTag(objectt.getKanalurl());
            }
            holder.normalkisisayisi.setText(channelbaba.get(position).getKisisayisi());
            Log.i("tago" , "getview kisisayisi kanaladapterposition" + position + "kisisayisi" + channelbaba.get(position).getKisisayisi());
            holder.normalkanaladi.setText(channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi());
            holder.normallikesayisi.setText(String.valueOf(channelbaba.get(position).getLikesayisi()));
            holder.normalgenel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    kanaladi = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getKanaladi();
                    String kanalid = channelbaba.get(position).getId();
                    String kanalurl = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getKanalurl();
                    int likedurumu = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getLikedurumu();
                    KanalaElemanEkle kEE = new KanalaElemanEkle();
                    kEE.execute(kanaladi);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GrupSohbeti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("intentname", "kanaladapter");
                    intent.putExtra("kanalmodu", "n");
                    intent.putExtra("kanaladi", kanaladi);
                    intent.putExtra("kanalid", kanalid);
                    intent.putExtra("kanalurl", kanalurl);
                    intent.putExtra("kanallikedurumu", likedurumu);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (kanalfilter == null) {

        }
        return kanalfilter;
    }


    static class KanalHolder {
        public ImageView normalgenel, officialgenel;
        public TextView normalkanaladi, officialkanaladitext, normalkisisayisi, normallikesayisi, officialkisisayisi, officiallikesayisi;
        public ImageButton menubutonu;
    }
```

This is error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                              at droxoft.armin.com.shappy.KanalAdapter.getItem(KanalAdapter.java:123)
                                                                              at droxoft.armin.com.shappy.KanalAdapter.getItemViewType(KanalAdapter.java:131)
                                                                              at com.felipecsl.quickreturn.library.widget.QuickReturnAdapter.getItemViewType(QuickReturnAdapter.java:109)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView(AbsListView.java:8228)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2707)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:661)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:6686)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:5685)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edited part :

```
private class KanallariYenidenCek extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String charset;
        String query;

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            charset = "utf-8";
            String param1 = "id";
            try {
                query = String.format("param1=%s", URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                return kanallarigor(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "olmadi";
            }
        }

        private String kanallarigor(String id) {
            channelbaba.clear();
            HttpURLConnection sconnection = null;
            try {
                sconnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://185.22.184.15/shappy//get_official_channels.php?id=" + id).openConnection();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment1 official kanalları gor bagı kuruldu");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            sconnection.setDoInput(true);
            sconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
            sconnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "* /*");
            sconnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            sconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

            try {
                OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(sconnection.getOutputStream());
                output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
                output.close();
                try {
                    int a = sconnection.getResponseCode();
                    String b = sconnection.getResponseMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedReader in;
                if (sconnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sconnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputline = in.readLine();
                    JSONArray jsono = new JSONArray(inputline);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                        Kanal kanal = new Kanal(true);
                        kanal.setKanaladi(object.optString("name"));
                        kanal.setDate("date");
                        kanal.setId(object.optString("id"));
                        kanal.setDistance(object.optString("distance"));
                        kanal.setLikesayisi(object.optInt("like_count"));
                        kanal.setLikedurumu(object.optInt("like_status"));
                        channelbaba.add(kanal);
                    }
                } else {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sconnection.getErrorStream()));
                    String inputline = in.readLine();
                    JSONArray jsono = new JSONArray(inputline);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                        Kanal kanal = new Kanal(true);
                        kanal.setKanaladi(object.optString("name"));
                        kanal.setDate("date");
                        kanal.setDistance(object.optString("distance"));
                        kanal.setId(object.optString("id"));
                        kanal.setLikedurumu(object.optInt("like_status"));
                        channelbaba.add(kanal);
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment yeniden official gor inputline yazd�m");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment yeniden official gor yazamad�m");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("tago", "json Exception");
            }

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://185.22.184.15/shappy/get_channels.php?id=" + id).openConnection();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment1 kanalları yeniden gor bagı kuruldu");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "* /*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

            try {
                OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
                output.close();
                try {
                    int a = connection.getResponseCode();
                    String b = connection.getResponseMessage();
                    Log.i("tago", "rerere1" + a + " " + b);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedReader in;
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputline = in.readLine();
                    JSONArray jsono = new JSONArray(inputline);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                        Kanal kanal = new Kanal(false);
                        kanal.setKanaladi(object.optString("name"));
                        kanal.setKanalurl(object.optString("photo"));
                        kanal.setDate("date");
                        kanal.setDistance(object.optString("distance"));
                        kanal.setLikesayisi(object.optInt("like_count"));
                        kanal.setId(object.optString("id"));
                        channelbaba.add(kanal);
                    }
                } else {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                    String inputline = in.readLine();
                    JSONArray jsono = new JSONArray(inputline);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                        Kanal kanal = new Kanal(false);
                        kanal.setKanaladi(object.optString("name"));
                        kanal.setKanalurl(object.optString("photo"));
                        kanal.setDate("date");
                        kanal.setDistance(object.optString("distance"));
                        kanal.setLikesayisi(object.optInt("like_count"));
                        kanal.setId(object.optString("id"));
                        channelbaba.add(kanal);
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment yeniden kanalları gor inputline yazd�m");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("tago", "Page Fragment yeniden kanalları gor yazamad�m");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("tago", "json Exception");
            }

            return "inputline";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            kanalAdapter = new KanalAdapter(getActivity(), channelbaba);
            if (viewGroup instanceof AbsListView) {
                int numColumns = (viewGroup instanceof GridView) ? 3 : 1;
                absListView.setAdapter(new QuickReturnAdapter(kanalAdapter, numColumns));
            }

            QuickReturnAttacher quickReturnAttacher = QuickReturnAttacher.forView(viewGroup);
            quickReturnAttacher.addTargetView(bottomTextView, AbsListViewScrollTarget.POSITION_BOTTOM);
            topTargetView = quickReturnAttacher.addTargetView(quickReturnBar,
                    AbsListViewScrollTarget.POSITION_BOTTOM,
                    dpToPx(getActivity(), 50));

            if (quickReturnAttacher instanceof AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher) {
                AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher
                        attacher =
                        (AbsListViewQuickReturnAttacher) quickReturnAttacher;
                attacher.addOnScrollListener(PageFragment1.this);
                attacher.setOnItemClickListener(PageFragment1.this);
                attacher.setOnItemLongClickListener(PageFragment1.this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is possible that the underlying data does not get refreshed - the error comes from `channelbaba.get(i);` in the `public Object getItem(int i)` method. Can you show the code where you make use of the adapter?

Comment: I am sure that data is refreshed

Comment: But that does not explain how the length becomes '0' if it is refreshed. Perhaps if you include the "swipe refresh" code we might pick something up there.

Answer (score 0):

To be able update the underlying data after swipe-refresh, you need to reload the list of channels in the `onRefresh` function of your `RefreshListener`.
So without seeing your `RefreshListener` code, I'd just suggest how it should look here:

```
yourSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
  new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {
       //update your adapter with a new list of channels?
       KanalAdapter updatedKanalAdapter = new KanalAdapter(context, channelbaba);
       mListView.setAdapter(updatedKanalAdapter);
       mListView.invalidateViews();
       yourSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didn't worked, i edited question